# Wrapping findbugs in a Junit test

Tags: java, junit, findbugs

Is there a library to go about doing this? I can't seem to find anything on this. Its as if I am the first person in the world to try to do this.

Comment: *"Its as if I am the first person in the world to try to do this"* - this is usually a warning flag. I, for one, have no idea what you're describing here and what you'd like to achieve.

Comment: Checking code with findbugs is often automated. Using maven the `findbugs-maven-plugin` can fail a build if it finds anything. How are you building the project?

Comment: @MattChampion I'm using Atlassian's Bamboo and I findbugs to behave like a junit test so that Bamboo can read its results and mark the build as failed if findbugs produces any issues.

Comment: There is a findbugs plugin for Bamboo but it does not seem well supported https://marketplace.atlassian.com/plugins/com.atlassian.bamboo.plugins.findbugs/server/overview

Comment: I've found the Java API for findbugs and the source code for the maven findbugs plugin. I've added a link to how the plugin runs findbugs https://github.com/gleclaire/findbugs-maven-plugin/blob/master/src/main/groovy/org/codehaus/mojo/findbugs/FindBugsMojo.groovy#L999 http://findbugs.sourceforge.net/api/index.html

Answer (score 0):

If you are looking to scan code project, you should be using the [FindBugs Maven plugin](http://gleclaire.github.io/findbugs-maven-plugin/) as mentions by [Matt Champion](https://stackoverflow.com/users/6081776/matt-champion).

If you are looking to tested your own [FindBugs detectors](http://findbugs.sourceforge.net/api/edu/umd/cs/findbugs/Detector.html), JUnit would make sens. You could reused test utilities such [FSB findbugs-test-util](https://github.com/find-sec-bugs/find-sec-bugs/tree/master/findbugs-test-util) ([test case example](https://github.com/find-sec-bugs/find-sec-bugs/blob/master/plugin/src/test/java/com/h3xstream/findsecbugs/scala/SslDisablerDetectorTest.java)) or [FindBugs' DetectorsTest](https://github.com/findbugsproject/findbugs/blob/master/findbugs/src/junit/edu/umd/cs/findbugs/DetectorsTest.java)